# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS doesn't recognize full memory?

Tags: ram, memory-usage

I have Pentium 4 Desktop, Intel D915PGN mother board with a full 4 GB of ram, but my Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit only recognize 3 GB of ram, do you guys have any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: can you post output of `free -m`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use 32-bit installation of Ubuntu. It's limited to 3GB of RAM (for technical reasons).
To use full memory upgrade to 64-bit version.

Comment: I said I have Ubuntu 64 Bit installed on my computer.

Comment: My bad, i didn't notice that.